# Install PHP 4.4.2 on 14.04

Tags: apache2, php

I need 4.4.2 due to compatibility reasons.

How do I install PHP 4.4.2 and Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04? Nothing displays in FireFox when I run any PHP.

Comment: Using chromium just shows the code, like PHP isn't installed. I followed the guide below plus the link supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you.
And also look here: [How To Install Ubuntu LAMP stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) (includes php)

```
wget http://uk.php.net/distributions/php-4.4.9.tar.gz
tar zxf php-4.4.9.tar.gz
cd php-4.4.9/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Followed both this and the DigitalOcean tutorial but still nothing working. It's like it's not installed, but if I install php5 that works file. I'm guessing there's no apt-get for previous versions?